# How To Use Leaflet.markercluster in a Layer Group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

So I'm trying to group my markers on my Leaflet Map using `Leaflet.markercluster`. Currently, I add my markers using a child in my `MapContainer` in my `App()` function:

```
return (
    <MapContainer
      ...
      <AddMarkers />
    </MapContainer>
);
```

For context, my `AddMarkers` function looks something like this:

```
function AddMarkers() {
  ...
  return (
    <LayerGroup>
      {users.map((user) => (
          <Marker
            ...
          </Marker>
        ))}
    </LayerGroup>
  );
}
```

In the `Leaflet.markercluster` [documentation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), they explain that you can add a marker cluster using the following idea:

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
markers.addLayer(L.marker(getRandomLatLng(map)));
... Add more layers ...
map.addLayer(markers);
```

How would I go about using the `L.markerClusterGroup()` method in my code? Would I have to rewrite how I add markers to my `MapContainer`?

Comment: I'm not really sure you can use Leaflet plugins in React-Leaflet. Btw try to use the [`useMap`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap) hook insde your `AddMarkers` component and call `map.addLayer(markers);` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by wrapping the `Markers` within a `MarkerClusterGroup` tag.

For example:

```
<MarkerClusterGroup>
      <Marker />
</MarkerClusterGroup>
```